# How can create two different android expendable list in one activity?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am working on my android application. I need a create a activity which has two expandable list. These list will have different layouts. So these list will be totally different. How can add two list to main layout? how can use "setadapter" for these different lists? Please give me some advice and if it is possible , some example code.

Thank you

Edit:

Thank you for response but where should I call switch function(setListAdapter(expListAdapter2)? I tried it in onGroupExpand but it didnt work properly. When I click the any group, I need the update specigic group not whole list, please help me if you have idea?

Comment: see if this helps http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating another adapter inside of your onCreate method.

Take the following

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try{
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
            new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        //FOR LEVEL 1 SCREEN
                    this,
                    createGroupList(),              // METHOD TO CREATE PARENTLIST Creating group List.
                    R.layout.group_row,             // REF TO XML FILENAME.         
                    new String[] { "Group Item" },  // STRING ARRAY HOLDING ONE KEY THAT REF'S ALL PARENT LIST ITEMS.
                    new int[] { R.id.row_name },    // REF TO I.D. OF PARENT XML. ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.                    
                    createChildList(),              // METHOD TO CREATE CHILD LST. childData describes second-level entries.
                    R.layout.child_row,             // XMLFILE NAME FOR CHILD LIST.Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                    new String[] {"Sub Item"},      // KEY FOR CHILD ITEMS IN HASHMAP. Keys in childData maps to display.
                    new int[] { R.id.grp_child}     // XML ID FOR TEXTVIEW. Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
                );

            setListAdapter( expListAdapter );// THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO CHANGE.
```

So if you now, (inside of that onCreate method), copy the expListAdapter and make another one called expListAdapter2, (You will need to create new arrays with items of the list, and copy and rename the "createGroupList()" method for each adapter you make.. Then you will be able to switch to the other list by simply changing the set adapter line to:

```
setListAdapter(expListAdapter2);
```

here are the creategroup and createchild methods that I used:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List createGroupList() { 
          ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < arrGroupelements.length; ++i ) { // for all elements in array........
            HashMap m = new HashMap();
            m.put("Group Item", arrGroupelements[i]); // the key and it's value.
            result.add( m );

            }     //in the end we have an array list


          return (List)result;
    }    


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List createChildList() {

        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < arrGroupelements.length ; ++i ) { // for each parent item
          ArrayList secList = new ArrayList(); 
          for( int n = 0 ; n < arrChildelements[i].length ; n++ ) {
            HashMap child = new HashMap();
            child.put("Sub Item", arrChildelements[i][n]);          
            secList.add( child );
          }
         result.add( secList );


        }        
        return result;
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: where do you call "setListAdapter(expListAdapter2)"?

Comment: Where should I call switch function? I tried in "onChildClickExpendable" didnt work, where did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Two expandable list in single layout...

```
expandableListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), createGroupList(),R.layout.reportsales_date, new String[] {"billdatevoid", "amount" }, new int[] {R.id.sales_date, R.id.sales_total },createChildList(), R.layout.reportsales_date1,
new String[] { "bill_num", "orderid" }, new int[] {R.id.bill_num, R.id.price });
setListAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), createGroupList1(),R.layout.report_date, new String[] { "GroupItem","GroupItem1" }, new int[] { R.id.datedate,R.id.datedate1 },createChildList1(), R.layout.report_date1,
new String[] { "InvoiceNo", "Invoiceamt" },new int[] { R.id.datebillno, R.id.dateamt });
expandableListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
```